# MongoDB connected to Robo 3T but data is not displayed

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, postman, robo3t

Image 1 -> User is saved in the database, information of all users is displayed here:
[image]

Image 2 -> Robo 3T not showing data:
[image]

As you can see the data is not displayed here, but when I try to get all users in postman, it shows that users are saved in the database(image 2)

Comment: can you show me the mongoose.connection in the code?

Comment: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/journalAnalysis', {
    useNewUrlParser : true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
}).then(() =>{
    console.log("DB CONNECTED")
})
`

Comment: disconnect the robo3t and connect to the local again

Comment: I took this out of the environment variable file(**mongodb://localhost:27017/journalAnalysis**) , and pasted in the code in order to show it to you, and it worked after reconnecting, thank you so much, Sir. Appreciate it.